# Display Data as Ledger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have a table `AdvanceEntry`.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Code   |    PaidDate   |     Amount     |    ReceiveDate    |  ReceiveAmount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  102    |   15-04-2004  |      3000      |     20-04-2004    |      2000  
  104    |   23-05-2006  |      1000      |       NULL        |      0.00
  104    |   25-05-2005  |      1500      |     12-06-2005    |       500
```

When any person tack the Loan then Loan amount is stored in the `Amount` column and date is stored in `PaidDate` and person code is stored in `Code` column. When that person gives back the amount then that amount is stored in `ReceiveAmount` and date is stored in `ReceiveDate`.

Now I want to create a report like ledger of a specific code.

For example code 102

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PaidDate / ReceiveDate    |    Amount    |  ReceiveAmount   |   Balance
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    15-04-2004             |    3000      |        0         |    3000
    20-04-2004             |     0        |      2000        |    1000
```

And for code 104

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PaidDate / ReceiveDate    |    Amount    |  ReceiveAmount   |   Balance
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    23-05-2006             |    1000      |        0         |    1000
    25-05-2005             |    1500      |        0         |    2500
    12-06-2005             |      0       |      500         |    2000
```

How can I do this? Please help me.. Thanks

Comment: This is probably possible in TSQL code, but it would be much better to use a reporting tool or a custom application to format the data for presentation. TSQL is not a good language for formatting or presenting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
with Paid as
(
  select Code
    , PaidDate
    , Amount
  from AdvanceEntry
  where PaidDate is not null
), Received as
(
  select Code
    , ReceiveDate
    , ReceiveAmount
  from AdvanceEntry
  where ReceiveDate is not null
), Details as
(
  select Code = coalesce(p.Code, r.Code)
    , CodeDate = coalesce(p.PaidDate, r.ReceiveDate)
    , Amount = sum(p.Amount)
    , ReceiveAmount = sum(r.ReceiveAmount)
  from Paid p
    full join Received r on p.PaidDate = r.ReceiveDate and p.Code = r.Code
  group by coalesce(p.Code, r.Code)
    , coalesce(p.PaidDate, r.ReceiveDate)
)
select d.Code
  , PayReceiveDate = d.CodeDate
  , Amount = isnull(d.Amount, 0.0)
  , ReceiveAmount = isnull(d.ReceiveAmount, 0.0)
  , Balance = isnull(b.Balance, 0.0)
from Details d
  outer apply (select Balance = sum(isnull(b.Amount, 0.0) - isnull(b.ReceiveAmount, 0.0))
              from Details b where d.Code = b.Code and d.CodeDate >= b.CodeDate) b
order by d.Code, d.CodeDate
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/628a2/6).

It also looks like you had a slight typo in your data; I've changed it slightly in the fiddle to get your expected results.

Also worth mentioning that if you are only getting one pay/receive action per day per code you can get away without any `GROUP BY` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

try this (untested):

```
;with cte as (
  select Code, PaidDate as Date, Amount as Dr, 0 as Cr, Amount as Net 
  from Data where PaidDate is not null 
  union all
  select Code, ReceivedData as Date, 0 as Dr, -ReceivedAmount as Cr, -ReceivedAmount as Net
  from Data where ReceivedDate is not null
)
select
  t1.*, sum(t2.Net) as Balance
from cte as t1
left join cte as t2 on t2.Code = t1.Code and t2.Date <= t1.Date
group by
  t1.Code, t1.Date
having t1.Code = @Code
```